# will any divisor of $0<a,b$ also divide $\gcd(a,b)$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Will any divisor of both $a,b>0$ also divide $\gcd(a,b)$?

Anyone have a proof of this if it is true, or counter in case of false? thanks,

Comment: What is your definition of gcd?

Answer (score 0):

Because the greatest common divisor of two integers is a linear combination of them. See the link kindly provided below.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézout%27s_identity

Comment: Or kindly provided in the duplicate above by Bill Dubuque....

Comment: @@@ Great thanks

Comment: @ghetto_department You are welcome. For your next question, the fourth one then, please google for answers here before posting. Usually questions on gcd have been answered already.

Comment: Dietrich Burde thank your for your useful comments! Order must be restored.

Comment: Yeah, I know, there is not always a unique solution here.